# array removeObjectsAtIndexes:

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I have a problem, with deleting items from an array..

first:
i have a variable of type int, called zan. in my HelloWordScene.h

```
int zan;
NSMutableArray * targets;
NSMutableArray *projectiles;
```

in my HelloWordScene.m. i have an object, animated:

```
-(id) init {
    if((self = [super init])) {
        [self schedule:@selector(update:)];
        _targets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        _projectiles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    [self schedule:@selector(gameLogic:) interval:3];
    return self;
}
```

in my selector I increment the var:

```
-(void)gameLogic:(ccTime)dt {
    [self addTarget];
    zan ++;
}
```

Later I have an animation and I have a addTarget:

```
// This loads an image of the same name (but ending in png), and goes through the
// plist to add definitions of each frame to the cache.
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"zancudo.plist"];

// Create a sprite sheet with the images
CCSpriteBatchNode *spriteSheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"zancudo.png"];
[self addChild:spriteSheet];

// Load up the frames of our animation
NSMutableArray *walkAnimFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
for(int i = 0; i <= 4; ++i) {
    [walkAnimFrames addObject:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"zancu000%d.png", i]]];
}
CCAnimation *walkAnim = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:walkAnimFrames delay:0.1f];

// Create a sprite for our bear
CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
self.bear = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"zancu0001.png"];



//random position
int minY = _bear.contentSize.width/2;
int maxY = winSize.width - _bear.contentSize.width/2;
int rangeY = maxY - minY;
int actualX = (arc4random() % rangeY) + minY;

// Create the target slightly off-screen along the right edge,
// and along a random position along the Y axis as calculated above
_bear.position = ccp(actualX,winSize.height + (_bear.contentSize.height/2));

self.walkAction = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:walkAnim restoreOriginalFrame:NO]];


//animation
[spriteSheet addChild:_bear];
//∫aqui pasar un for para poder saber que position es
CCLOG(@"cantidad de zancudos%d",zan);
[_targets insertObject:_bear atIndex:zan];
```

i have deleted a mutable _target for index- i have a selector update. try delete a mutablearray this.

```
for (CCSprite *target in targetsToDelete) {
        if (_targets.count!=0) {
            for (int j=1; j==_targets.count; j++) {
                [_targets removeObjectAtIndex:j];
            }

        }
```

I need help

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM removeObjectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
 i'ts the error

Comment: http://youtu.be/glO0I7VMJ30 the problem no delete the sprite... god..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use syntax like this for crash free delete;

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithArray: _targets];

for(CCSprite *sprite in array)
{
    if(sprite.tag == kToDelete) //mark somewhere in game :or use ur logic here
    {
        [_targets removeObject: sprite];
        [sprite stopAllActions];
        [sprite removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: @user1700639, if it is in dealoc method then just removeAllObject s ok..if it is in between then we can use above syntax...i thought he want to delete in between..not in dealoc...anyway thx for the info

Answer (score 0):

Your loop will try and access an index out of the array's bounds...try this

```
for (int j = 0; j == _targets.count - 1; j++) 
{                 
     [_targets removeObjectAtIndex:j];             
}
```

However, since it appears you are only removing the last element of the array with this code, you could skip the for loop and use:

```
[_targets removeLastObject];
```

Comment: i the first touch... no, delete

Comment: the ..ok... the error is. Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds for empty array'

Answer (score 0):

The moment you remove an object from _targets, the effective count actually changes. So if you start the loop with a count of 10, and eventually the value of j will be out of bounds. I dont follow quite well the logic of your if ( the == ), but if you are trying to remove all objects, instead of the loop :

```
[_targets removeAllObjects];
```

Comment: i have the problem no delete the sprite... and walkanimation se.. my video in youtube... http://youtu.be/glO0I7VMJ30